# React Freezes For A Few Seconds When Doing Expensive Calculations In UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, react-hooks

I have the following code below for basically a chess bot who will calculate the next move:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (botTurn) {
            const statusJSON = status(game.fen());
            const aiMoveIs = aiMove(statusJSON, botAi);

            console.log(aiMoveIs);
        }
    }, [botTurn])
```

There are no problems with the aiMove function, however it just takes a long time to calculate and returns the `aiMoveIs` constant in a few seconds which is expected. However, whenever the aiMove function is calculating, the entire React App freezes until it finishes. I want the aiMove function to kinda 'run in the background' and not freeze the entire react app and return the aiMoveIs variable when done. How do I go along doing this? Async? Please help. Also note theres no problem with any of the useState and other constants like `botAi`, `game.fen()` or etc.

Comment: Page JS is single-threaded, so whatever synchronous tasks you're running are going to block the _entire JS thread_ while they run. If this function can do its work on its own (i.e. without needing the DOM etc) then definitely give [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or even [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) a try.

Comment: Can I for example us an API? I can give it the position of the chess game and it can give me back the best move? Will it stop freezing then?

Comment: try to optimize the function. i dont know what the logic is, but you could add more variables and memoize the previous result. I think the issue is everytime you run this function you are starting from the beginning

Comment: Its a chess ai, you cant memoize that?? all I want is for it to run in the background

Comment: @VivaanKumar do you find a way to do this kind of expensive tasks in background ? i need to load a list of sounds while i show a loading indicator but the app freezes when i enter to the screen, even before the loading indicator is rendered.